# How to toggle column visibility programmatically (through data binding) of ASP.NET AJAX Telerik component?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I have couple checkboxes on the form and RadGrid component.  I'm seeing that there is Visible property of that component but I need to bind it to the check box that will toggle column's visibility.  How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show some code of you've done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following post from Telerik's community forum contains links to examples of how to do this from both the client side and the server side.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/chart/how-can-i-hide-unhide-columns-in-rad-grid.aspx

The following post from the same site contains a source code example for the server side that is very simple and direct.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/how-to-hide-columns-in-radgrid.aspx